# Logstash shut down and stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit)

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Let me say right away that I am not a professional.
I have a problem with Logstash. A few days ago it stopped collecting data and I found an error in the logs. Before it stopped collecting data, changes were made to logstash.conf, but I had a backup copy of logstash.conf on which everything initially worked.
Therefore, I checked with a backup copy of logstash.conf - but the error still remained.
Please tell me what else I can check?

```
[docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:17:38,066][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j        configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:17:38,161][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting     Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.4.2.0 (3.1.0) 2023-03-08 90d2913fda     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.8+7 on 17.0.8+7 +indy +jit [x86_64-linux]"}
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:17:38,164][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap     flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, 
        -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -    Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, 
        -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Dls.cgroup.cpuacct.path.override=/, -    Dls.cgroup.cpu.path.override=/, 
        -Xms256m, -Xmx256m, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, 
        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-    exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED, 
        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-    exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED, 
        --add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-    opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, 
        --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-    UNNAMED, 
        --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-    opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:17:54,528][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully     started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:19:15,265][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to     execute action {
    :action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
    :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", 
    :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \"filter\", \"output\" at line 1, column 1     (byte 1)", 
    :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", 
             "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:239:in `initialize'", 
             "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:173:in `initialize'", 
             "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48:in `initialize'", 
             "org/jruby/RubyClass.java:931:in `new'", 
             "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:49:in `execute'", 
             "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:386:in `block in converge_state'"]}
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:19:15,569][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut     down.
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m [2024-02-27T20:19:15,616][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m     at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:795) ~     [jruby.jar:?]
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m     at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:758) ~    [jruby.jar:?]
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m     at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>    (/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:90) ~[?:?]
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
    [docker-elk-logstash-1 |[0m Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured     via log4j2.properties
```

Our logstash file configuration looks like this:

```
input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    
    filter {
      if [message] =~ /Error/ {
        grok {
          match => { "message" => ["(?:Error:(?<error_exception>.*))"] }
        }
        mutate {
          add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_host_error]" => "%{[fields][hostname]}" }
          add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_key_error]" => "gate_error" }
          add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_msg_error]" => "%{message}" }
        }
      }
      }
    output {
      stdout { codec => rubydebug }
      } else if [message] =~ /Error/ {
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
          user => "logstash_internal"
          password => "${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}"
          index => "error-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
        }
        zabbix {
          zabbix_host => "[@metadata][zabbix_host_error]"
          zabbix_server_host => "my_IP"
          zabbix_server_port => my_port
          zabbix_key => "[@metadata][zabbix_key_error]"
          zabbix_value => "[@metadata][zabbix_msg_error]"
        }
      }
```

I understand that the log says that the error is in:

```
message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"input\", \"filter\", \"output\" at line 1, column 1 (byte 1)"
```

But I don't see any error there..(

Tried:

- launching with a known working config;
- docker restart container;
- completely restart the cluster;
- docker compose down && docker compose up --build -d.

Comment: Solution:
Along the path ~/docker-elk/logstash/pipeline , in addition to logstash.conf, there was another file that should not have been there. It is not known how it got there, but after removing it, the problem was completely solved.